# Check string value of boolean to a mapped enum

Tags: java

In a project, a boolean can be mapped to an enum to display a custom string for `true` and `false`.
If I have a string interpretation of a value, I have a method that is checking against the custom enum names or/and against regular boolean expressions like `true`, `false`, `0` and `1`.

The method looks like this

```
public Boolean createParameterObjectValue(String value) {
    if (getMetaData().getValidValues().isAvailable() && getMetaData().getValidValues().getType() == ValidValues.Type.ENUM) {
        if (getMetaData().getValidValues(EnumValidValues.class).getEnumName(1).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (getMetaData().getValidValues(EnumValidValues.class).getEnumName(0).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return false;
        }
        //TODO refactor redundance
        return !("0".equals(value) || "FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase(value));
    } else {
            return !("0".equals(value) || "FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase(value));
    }
}
```

First I'll check if the object in my project (a parameter) that is handling the `boolean` value, has defined values and has an `enum` mapping.

If this is true, compare the value to the `enum` names. If none of them equals the given value,I assume that the given string is `"0"`,`"1"`,`"false"` or `"true"`. The same happens if the parameter does not have an `enum` mapping.

As you see from the TODO comment I'm not really happy with the redundancy, even if it doesn't really affect the performance. How could I remove the redundancy from this code?

Answer (score 2):

The redundant logical expression seems to be too complex for this case.

And there is probably a bug. You say that the expected set of values for it is ("0", "1", "false", "true"), but if value = "2", it will also evaluate to "true":

```
!("0".equals("2") || "FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase("2")); ->

!(false || false) -> !false -> true
```

"2" is weird for "true" value.

So I suggest to reformulate the expression to

```
Boolean.parseBoolean(value) || "1".equals(value)
```

"1" is still there, because `parseBoolean` checks for equivalence for "true" string value.

The logic of the entire method can be thus reformulated with improved readability and simplified:

```
public boolean createParameterObjectValue2(String value) {
  return Boolean.parseBoolean(value) ||
         "1".equals(value) ||
         evaluatesToTrueFromMetadata(value);
}

private boolean evaluatesToTrueFromMetadata(String value) {
  return getMetaData().getValidValues().isAvailable() &&
      getMetaData().getValidValues().getType() == ValidValues.Type.ENUM &&
      getMetaData().getValidValues(EnumValidValues.class).getEnumName(1).equalsIgnoreCase(value);
}
```

`getMetaData().getValidValues()` in the private method should also be extracted to a local reference in order to shorten the expression.

Comment: Yes it's on purpose that the function is testing on `false`. As per logic definition `0` is `false`, and therefor any other value has to be `true`.

Comment: in this case you can keep the part `!"0".equals(value)`.

Comment: But you are right. as Java goes the other way around it probably would make most sense go for the compromise `!("0".equals(value)) || Boolean.parseBoolean(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that I missed the wood for the trees...

The solution is rather simple. I'm able to remove the redundancy be just removing the else block... obviously.

```
public Boolean createParameterObjectValue(String value) {
    if (getMetaData().getValidValues().isAvailable() && getMetaData().getValidValues().getType() == ValidValues.Type.ENUM) {
        if (getMetaData().getValidValues(EnumValidValues.class).getEnumName(1).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (getMetaData().getValidValues(EnumValidValues.class).getEnumName(0).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return false;
        }
   }
   return !("0".equals(value) || "FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase(value));
}
```